# Model validation on a page model wrapping a DTO

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, .net-core, cqrs

I have been playing around with ASP.NET Core MVC for quite a while and now I'm facing an set-back. I have implemented my project using CQRS using mediatR and automapper but I cannot seem to find  proper way to validate my page models.

My design is based on have the entities separated from the pages. The commands/queries return a page model which usually wraps a DTO which implements has a profile for inline maps to map from an entity to the DTO.

How could one use validation and display error messages to the page by validating a DTO wrapped inside a page model?

Now, for some demo code:

A demo query:

```
namespace HM.Application.Queries
{
    public class GetAllMedicsQuery : IRequest<MedicIndexModel> { }

    public class GetAllMedicsQueryHandler : IRequestHandler<GetAllMedicsQuery, MedicIndexModel>
    {
        private readonly IMedicRepository _medicRepository;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        private readonly ILogger<GetAllMedicsQueryHandler> _logger;

        public GetAllMedicsQueryHandler(IMedicRepository medicRepository, IMapper mapper, ILogger<GetAllMedicsQueryHandler> logger)
        {
            _medicRepository = medicRepository;
            _mapper = mapper;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task<MedicIndexModel> Handle(GetAllMedicsQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var medics = await _medicRepository.GetAllMedics();
            MedicIndexModel medicIndexModel = new MedicIndexModel()
            {
                Medics = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<MedicIndexDTO>>(medics)
            };

            return medicIndexModel;
        }
    }
}
```

The page model:

```
namespace HM.Application.ViewModels
{
    public class MedicIndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<MedicIndexDTO> Medics { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the DTO:

```
namespace HM.DTO
{
    public class MedicIndexDTO : IHaveCustomMapping
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string rank { get; set; }

        public void CreateMappings(Profile configuration)
        {
            configuration.CreateMap<Medic, MedicIndexDTO>()
                .ForMember(medicDto => medicDto.id, options => options.MapFrom(medic => medic.Id))
                .ForMember(medicDto => medicDto.firstName, options => options.MapFrom(medic => medic.firstName))
                .ForMember(medicDto => medicDto.lastName, options => options.MapFrom(medic => medic.lastName))
                .ForMember(medicDto => medicDto.email, options => options.MapFrom(medic => medic.Email))
                .ForMember(medicDto => medicDto.rank, options => options.MapFrom(medic => medic.rank));
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look [here](https://jimmybogard.com/contoso-university-examples-with-cqrs-mediatr-automapper-and-more/). And also, all those MapFrom-s are useless, they kind of defeat the purpose of AM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a custom page model, let it be `MyCustomPageModel` which inherits `PageModel` and it contains a DTO of some kind. This DTO contains some properties which have attribute validation or other form of validation. When used as the page model, the validation will still work for the fields inside the DTO, although it does not inherit himself the `PageModel`. To put it together, one can write

```
public class MyCustomPageModel : PageModel {
    public SomeDTO dto  {get; set;}
}
```

and have working validation!